# Multi-level em um OL

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando obter o seguinte resultado:

> 1. Apresentacao
>
>    1.1. Conteudo
>
>    1.2. Programação
>
>    1.2.1. JAVA
>
>    1.2.2. DOTNET
> 2. Conclusão
>
>    2.1. Agradecimentos
>
>    2.1.1 Família
>
>    2.1.2. Professores
> 3. Fim

Através do seguinte `HTML`:

```
<ol>
    <li>Apresentacao</li>
    <ol>
        <li> Conteudo </li>
        <li> Programação </li>
        <ol>
            <li> JAVA </li>
            <li> DOTNET </li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <li>Conclusão</li>
    <ol>
        <li> Agradecimentos</li>
         <ol>
            <li> Família </li>
            <li> Professores </li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <li>Fim</li>
</ol>
```

Cheguei mais perto através do seguinte `CSS`:

```
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/scpr8gp9/)

Porém ele ainda gera alguns problemas.

Existe algum recurso do `CSS` ou `HTML` para conseguir chegar no meu resultado?

Comment: O que ainda está faltando? As margens?

Comment: @Earendul, ele coloca os números errados.

Comment: Hmm, é mesmo. Vou ver se consigo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa deixar aberto a tag `<li>` a cada nível e fechar quando começa outro nível.

Código corrigido:

```css
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
<ol>
    <li class="reseta">Apresentacao
     <ol>
      <li> Conteudo </li>
      <li> Programação </li>
      <ol>
          <li> JAVA </li>
          <li> DOTNET </li>
         </ol>
     </ol>
    </li>
 <li class="reseta">Conclusão
        <ol>
            <li> Agradecimentos</li>
             <ol>
                <li> Família </li>
                <li> Professores </li>
            </ol>
        </ol>
    </li>
 <li>Fim</li>
</ol>
```

Exemplo no [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqbpu18c/)

Answer (score 2):

Uma possível solução:

```
body {
    counter-reset: chapter; /* contador de capitulos */
}
ol {
   list-style-type: none;
}
.chapter > li:before {
   counter-increment: chapter; 
   content: counter(chapter)"."; 
}
ol.section {
    counter-reset: section;
}

ol.section > li:before { 
    content: counter(chapter)"."counter(section)" "; 
    counter-increment: section;
}

ol.subsection {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}

ol.subsection > li:before { 
    content: counter(chapter)"."counter(section)"."counter(subsection)" "; 
    counter-increment: subsection;
}
```

E, no HTML

```
<ol class="chapter">
    <li>Apresentacao</li>
    <ol class="section">
        <li> Conteudo </li>
        <li> Programação </li>
        <ol class="subsection">
            <li> JAVA </li>
            <li> DOTNET </li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <li>Conclusão</li>
    <ol class="section">
        <li> Agradecimentos</li>
         <ol class="subsection">
            <li> Família </li>
            <li> Professores </li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <li>Fim</li>
</ol>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scpr8gp9/1/)

Comment: Eu *acho* que semanticamente não faz sentido colocar `ol` dentro de `ol`. O correto seria somente ter `li`s dentro de `ol` ou `ul`, sendo que o aninhamento é feito dentro do `li` (como na resposta do Earendul). Mas posso estar enganado, a [especificação do HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2) dá um exemplo, mas marca-o como "obsoleto" (*deprecated*), sem no entanto oferecer uma alternativa. A [especificação candidata do HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) sequer toca no assunto...